# How to arrange element inside of FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I work on an Android app and I use as view a FrameLayout. The problem is one of design. Inside of view,  I have another FrameLayout, and a LinearLayout, that is positioned on the bottom view. But the problem is that when my FrameLayout is higher than parent, the last part of the FrameLayout is under the LinearLayout, and in this case I want, that my view from FrameLayout to occupay all part less the height of the LinearLayout.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

And here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
    android:paddingTop="8dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentOffersMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/products"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_menu_text_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/receiptStatusMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/receipt"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_menu_text_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/photographReceiptMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/camera"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_menu_text_size"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userAccountMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/account"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_menu_text_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/howItWorksMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/information"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_menu_text_size" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can someoane to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `content_frame` has to be alway above the `LinearLayout`, way not punnitng them in a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` parent? Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
    android:paddingTop="8dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentOffersMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/products"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_menu_text_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/receiptStatusMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/receipt"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_menu_text_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/photographReceiptMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/camera"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_menu_text_size"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userAccountMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/account"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_menu_text_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/howItWorksMenu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/information"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/bottom_menu_text_size" />
    </LinearLayout>

<!-- Close the parent layout -->
</LinearLayout>
```